# Word for varied with equal spacing

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a less clumsy way to say:

> The phase advance in the measurement plane was varied between the corrector lenses and the measurement screen.

Also with the additional constraint that the variation has to be equally spaced which is defined in the next sentence. I would prefer to put all the information into one sentence. The context is a scientific paper.

Comment: I think we're going to need the full context, and/or a description of what that phrase actually means.

Comment: @AndrewLeach. Okey done.

Comment: Would the adjective " equidistant" help?

Comment: I am still not quite sure what the sentence is supposed to say. The transitive use of *vary* is odd. The sentence feels like a crucial bit has been left out.

Comment: @Josh61. Hm something like: ... plane was scanned using equidstant steps between ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example sentence, as it stands, is ambiguous; on the one hand, it might be saying that phase advance was experimentally controlled; on the other, that measurements showed variation.  Use an active rather than passive construction to avoid that ambiguity:

> We varied phase advance in the measurement plane linearly between the corrector lenses and the measurement screen.
>   We measured linear variation of phase advance in the measurement plane between the corrector lenses and the measurement screen.

I've used the word  *[linear](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/linear#Adjective)* (in sense 5, “Of or relating to a class of polynomial of the form y = ax + b”) to express one possible interpretation of the phrase “the variation has to be equally spaced”.  Also consider use of  *[proportional](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proportional#Adjective)* (“At a constant ratio (to), In proportion (to)”).

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about this ambiguity. Sorry for the confussion. I think linear is good fit of word for this as well as going reconstructing the sentence into the active form. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @jwpat7's answer, I suggest the following to communicate that you used equally sized steps (e.g., 7):

> We varied phase advance in the measurement plane in 7 equal steps between the corrector lenses and the measurement screen.